# Angular 8 FormGroup async validation from API call

Tags: angular8, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

> I need to validate **Unique product title, except the current product
>   id.**

Please note that I need to validate **FormGroup using async validation - API service call**.

The function contains hardcoded value 2, please ignore it.

**product-component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.productForm = this.fb.group({
      categoryId: ['', [Validators.required]],
      title: ['', [Validators.required]],
      description: [''],
      oldPrice: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10), Validators.pattern('^\\d+$')]],
      newPrice: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10), Validators.pattern('^\\d+$')]]
}, 
// {validators: ValidateUniqueProductTitle.checkProductTitle(this.productService, 2)}
{asyncValidators: [ValidateUniqueProductTitle.checkProductTitle(this.productService, 2)]}
);
```

**Validate class:**

```
export class ValidateUniqueProductTitle {

public static checkProductTitle(productService: ProductService, productId) {
    return (group: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
        return productService.checkExisting(group.controls['title'].value, productId)
                            .pipe(
                                debounceTime(200),
                                distinctUntilChanged(),
                                take(1),
                                map((data: boolean) => {
                                    console.log('checkExisting api called', data);
                                    return data ?  {title_exists: true} : null;
                                })
                            ); 
        }
}
```

> **Issue:**
>
> Validate class function is never called when I use this line:
>
> `{asyncValidators:[ValidateUniqueProductTitle.checkProductTitle(this.productService, 2)]}`
>
> When I use this line, function gets called but API is not fired:
>
> `{validators: ValidateUniqueProductTitle.checkProductTitle(this.productService, 2)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a silly mistake. Should have used `FormGroup` instead of `Abstract Control` type in return.

**Validate class:**

```
export class ValidateUniqueProductTitle {

  public static checkProductTitle(productService: ProductService, productId) {
       return (group: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
            return productService.checkExisting(group.controls['title'].value, productId)
                        .pipe(
                            debounceTime(200),
                            distinctUntilChanged(),
                            take(1),
                            map((data: boolean) => {
                                console.log('checkExisting api called', data);
                                return data ?  {title_exists: true} : null;
                            })
                        ); 
    }
}
```

Also, it's important to note that:

> Async validators are fired only when all sync validators return null.

I was expecting all validation errors (sync and async) to appear together, but that doesn't happen.